# Query Take more time on scope_identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, sqlperformance

When I use

```
Select @lastIdentity = scope_identity from TableName
```

It take a lot of time, and when I use

```
select  @lastIdentity = scope_identity
```

It take a little time.

So what is the difference?

Comment: Why are you specifying `from TableName`, that will just cause an unnecessary scan of the table without selecting any columns, what purpose does it serve? `scope_identity()` can (and should) be used without a table reference, it just gives you the last insert ID on the current connection. See docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Your first query will still scan every row in the table even though it has no actual logical effect on the assignment. And I suggest you should generally use SET rather than SELECT to assign scalar variables. I hope that is sufficient hint for you to research the difference.